# Is my logic correct? I'm trying to do a simple search from a database

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, visual-studio-2010, ado.net

This is my code for the search function

```
string strRFID = "SELECT patientID FROM RFID WHERE rfidentification=@rfidSearch";
SqlCommand cmdRFID = new SqlCommand(strRFID, connection);
cmdRFID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfidSearch", txtRFID.Text);


string strPatient = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID=" + "'" + strRFID + "'";
SqlCommand cmdPatient = new SqlCommand(strPatient, connection);

connection.Open();
SqlDataReader readRFID = cmdRFID.ExecuteReader();
readRFID.Close();

SqlDataReader readPatient = cmdPatient.ExecuteReader();

if (readPatient.Read())
{
    txtFirstName.Text = readPatient["pFirstName"].ToString();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("No record found");
}

readPatient.Close();
connection.Close();
```

I keep receiving this error message: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT patientID FROM RFID WHERE rfidentification=@rfidSearch' to data type int."  Been stuck at for hours, I can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're appending the subquery as a string value. Remove the single quotes

```
string strPatient = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID= (" +  strRFID+")" ;
```

Comment: It says here Must declare the scalar variable "@rfidSearch"

Comment: Add the @rfidSearch parameter to cmdPatient

Answer (score 0):

**Problem1 :** You are not providing the Command object Text.
**Solution1 :** you need to provide the Command object Text using `CommandText` property

Try This:

```
string strPatient = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID IN ("+cmdRFID.CommandText+")";
```

**Solution 2:** if you want to do a proper search use keyword `LIKE` instead of equals `=` operator and also use  `%` symbol before and after the search text in the first query.

**Complete Code:**

```
string strRFID = "SELECT patientID FROM RFID WHERE rfidentification like @rfidSearch";
SqlCommand cmdRFID = new SqlCommand(strRFID, connection);
cmdRFID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rfidSearch", "%"+ txtRFID.Text+ "%");
string strPatient = "SELECT * FROM PATIENT WHERE patientID IN ("+cmdRFID.CommandText+")";
```

Comment: Now it giving me this error: Must declare the scalar variable "@rfidSearch"